# Why isn't htaccess following this php_value directive?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

In .htaccess I've added

```
php_value session.name "SID"
```

This seems to have no effect, however, and no errors are thrown in error_log.  Other rewrite rules in the same .htaccess file are working as expected.

Why isn't htaccess following this php_value directive? And is there a way to test if php_values or php_flags are being used?

PHP 5.3.8 is running as an Apache 2.2.21 module, not CGI.

UPDATE: Adding php_value session.name "SID" to default-server.conf works as intended.  I'm still not sure how this doesn't work in the .htaccess though.  In default-server.conf I have 'AllowOverride All' and 'Options All' (for testing this).

Comment: Does setting other php_values work in the .htaccess file? Can you verify by having a page display the output of phpinfo() ?

Comment: Could you suggest a php_value to test for?  What should I verify via phpinfo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I am using virtual hosts but was editing my default-server.conf file.  Once I realized this and edited the correct file in the vhost.d directory the php_value setting was picked up from the .htaccess file as expected.